# manual / script ssh difference

Tags: python, ssh

I am able to log into a machine using SSH manually and using a Python script. Both succeed in logging in.

From the manual attempt, if I run the script signmes1.py, it works.

From the Python script, if I run the same script using the command

```
os.system("python signmes1.py")
```

it does not work, and has the following error. The file it is complaining about definitely exists and loads if I run the script manually. Why would it make any difference if I am using exactly the same command but in a script?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "signmes1.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open("result1.txt", "r") as my_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'result1.txt'
```

The code I use in my script to log in is the following:

```
import ssh
import os

s = ssh.Connection(host = 'ipaddress', username = 'server1', password = 'xxxx')
```

Where ipaddress is the ipaddress, and password is my password. The log in works well as far as I can see, I can copy things over to the remote server and copy them back to the local machine.

Comment: Before Running `os.system()`, can you print `os.getcwd()` and make sure that you are in the same directory where result1.txt is supposed to be?

Comment: I have put that into the script and there is no output, apart from the traceback I mentioned above.

Comment: can you paste the code how you are logging in before running `os.system()`. are you using paramiko ?

Comment: I'm not using paramiko, just the python ssh module. I have added the requested information alongside the main question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure. Is your code something like this?

```
import ssh
import os

s = ssh.Connection(host = 'ipaddress', username = 'server1', password = 'xxxx') 
os.system("python signmes1.py")
```

If yes, things wont run fine for you. If no, please edit the question and paste the full code

Comment: apologies, that is exactly how i am logging in, and then running the os.system command. i'm confused about the <br> however. may i ask why it won't run fine however? what's wrong with it please?

Comment: I think the <br> is only a presentational issue. ;)

Comment: you can ignore <br>. I have edited that (my bad formatting).
If you are running `os.system`, you are not running it on the new host, you are still trying to run signames1.py in the current system that you are on. For running on the new host on which you have done ssh, you need to use `s`

Comment: I think you are right. os.system sends to the local machine. can you please give a little more information on what i need to use, all you have said is 's'.

Comment: If I do tell you that, I think the question will be tagged as homework. Its pretty easy. Just print help(s) and it will show you what functions you can use.